# Valores com 3 casas decimais inserindo erroneamente

Tags: c#, arredondamento

Possuo um textbox em que informo um valor  de um item que deve ser dividido para 10 pessoas cadastradas no sistema, mas que sejam divididos por proporção, quem tem mais item recebe mais do novo valor informado, quem tem menos receberá menos.

O sistema está dividindo corretamente, porem sempre com 0,001 centavo a mais ou a menos, nao batendo a conta, por exemplo se informei 100 no valor e inseri no banco ao fazer a soma sempre está 99,999 ou 100,001 nao fechando a conta, estou usando

```
Math.Round((decimal)valor, 3)
```

para pegar somente 3 casas após a virgula, porem sempre da essa diferença no final, alguem consegue me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Respeito a decisão do colega de achar que essa pergunta é duplicada, porem discordo. Os topicos mencionados pelo mesmo diz "Como representar o tipo real" não é isso que eu quero. A outra diz como converter string para double, tb não é isso que quero. Minha variavel nao é string e decimal que nao bate valor da 3 casa decimal ao somar. A primeira diz que tipos de dados usar, tb nao é isso que quero ja que eu sei o tipo de dados que tenho que usar: "decimal". A questão é somente o pq de a 3ª casa nao estar respeitando o valor correto em questao...

Comment: Stand se pode colocar a conta, como exemplo minimo? já visto que está usando um tipo decimal, talvez na divisão tem algo que possamos apontar.